# Is incineration of a solid fuel complete or incomplete?

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science, physical-chemistry, combustion

If I have some solid material like biomass and incinerate it at 1000 Celsius degrees for 15 minutes in an oxidized atmosphere within an incineration oven. As an output it gives me ash. Is the incineration complete or incomplete? Like for example we have incomplete combustion (lack of oxygen) and complete combustion (enriched oxygen medium). What about this incineration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends entirely on the conditions.

If there is enough oxygen to make the mixture stoichiometric or oxygen-rich, and it burns for long enough at a high-enough temperature. However, the precise meaning of each of those three "enough"s will change with the material, so it is impossible to give a definitive answer for a non-specific case.

As a general rule, the darker the ash produced by the combustion, the less complete the combustion process, as a darker color is typically caused by remaining charcoal (unburned hydrocarbons). If you start with biomass, it will consist of a lot of hydrogen (which forms water and evaporates), carbon (which, if completely combusted, forms gaseous carbon dioxide), nitrogen (which forms gaseous N$_2$ or NO$_x$) as well as a sundry mix of other elements, which will cool down into mineral oxides in the ash. What that will look like will depend on what those added elements were in the initial biomass.

Comment: Right, I understand, thank you! Basically I have say a solid biomass fuel, I put it say in the incineration oven at around 1000 degrees Celsius for 15 minutes, the atmosphere has oxygen, then I take the sample out in order to find out the ash composition of it (the ash quantity), that's what I thought that it should be a complete incineration...but it was a bit confusing for me. I know for complete combustion we get H2O and CO2, whilst for incomplete combustion we get soot and mostly CO...

Comment: @xtyper 15 minutes might be enough. Or they might not. (Hint: as an example, cremating a human body can take two hours or more.) It depends on the amount of biomass and its configuration. As I said, it depends on the conditions, and asking about numbers without giving specific configuration is completely pointless.

Comment: Thank you! Well as it is at small lab scale the biomass would be few hundreds grams say for example 200 grams of biomass, 1000 degrees C, 15 minutes in the incineration oven where oxygen is present in the chamber. I was told that after this incineration of biomass I get ash content, but I wasn't told if the incineration is complete or not, as is the case for combustion.